# Extend Wordpress Search

Tags: plugins, search

I've been using a plugin that creates it's own tables in the database to store restaurant menus. Is there any way to enable the WP search function to return matching results from it along with regular posts?

Comment: Populating database *only* for searching is NOT a good idea to me unless you maintain a record for a logged in user's search, like the *Search History* of Google's registered users. ...And the saying *to enable the WP search function to return matching results* is not a clear question. Please edit your question and elaborate with more details of the concept.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood me. I've amended my question  so hopefully it makes more sense. Thanks

Comment: @user2739763 how the custom tables are structurated? Which are the columns you want to search?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question but these are the columns of a table called 'wprmm_items':

 id name description price second_price image icon_class show_price active display_order menu_id category_id